# Do RE5: Lost in Nightmares and Desperate Escape story DLCs have to be completed in one sitting?

Tags: resident-evil-5

[Lost in Nightmares](http://residentevil.wikia.com/wiki/Lost_in_Nightmares) seems to only use checkpoints, in Resident Evil series those haven't traditionally been save points but locations to restart from after failure state. Is this how [Desperate Escape](http://residentevil.wikia.com/wiki/Desperate_Escape) plays too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. I've had the experience myself.
No shut-down safe checkpoints RE5 DLCs.